# Bash - Remove XML nodes if the attribute value of a child node does not equal a specific value?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xmlstarlet

I have RSS feed, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title>my feed</title>
  <link rel="self" href="http://myhomesite.com/articles/feed/"/>
  <updated>2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</updated>
  <id>http://myhomesite.com/articles/feed/?dt=2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</id>
  <entry>
    <id>id0</id>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://yandex.ru/link123"/>
    <author>
      <name/>
    </author>
    <published>2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</published>
    <updated>2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</updated>
    <title type="html"><![CDATA[foo bar foo bar]]></title>
    <content type="html"><![CDATA[]]></content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>id2</id>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://myhomesite.com"/>
    <author>
      <name/>
    </author>
    <published>2019-11-04T09:45:00Z</published>
    <updated>2019-11-04T09:45:00Z</updated>
    <title type="html"><![CDATA[foo bar foo bar]]></title>
    <content type="html"><![CDATA[]]></content>
  </entry>
....
```

I want remove all nodes (`/feed/entry`) where **link** **href** != `http://myhomesite.com`.

How do I remove XML node where value start at specified symbols using Bash?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, start with finding a command-line XML parser/modifier suitable for this task

Comment: @oguzismail i see to  xmlstarlet ed -d "/feed/entry" file.rss but ..

Comment: I would recommend using python/java or any other programming language rather than bash to load/parse/dump the xml and properly work with it. If you are familiar with python, you can consider the `minidom` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash features by themselves are not very well suited parsing XML.

This renowned [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/113) states the following:

> **Do not** attempt *[to extract data from an XML file]* with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), and so on (it leads to [undesired results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)).

Consider utilizing an XML specific command line tool, such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php). See download info [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php) if you don't already have XML Starlet installed.

---

### Solution:

Using XML Starlet you can run the following command to output the desired results to your terminal:

```
xml ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -d '//x:entry[not(child::x:link[@href="https://myhomesite.com"])]' /path/to/file.rss
```

<sub>**Note:** The `/path/to/file.rss` part at the end of the command shown above should be substituted with the real pathname to the actual `.rss` file.</sub>

**Explanation:**

The parts of the aforementioned command breakdown as follows:

- **`xml`** - invoke the XML Starlet command.
- **`ed`** - Edit/Update the XML document.
- **`-N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`** - The [`-N`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04.html) option binds the namespace, i.e. `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`, to a prefix that we've arbitrarily named `x`.
- **`-d`** - delete node(s) that are matched.
- **`'//x:entry[not(child::x:link[@href="https://myhomesite.com"])]'`** The [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression used to find/match the appropriate nodes as specified in your question.

  > *all nodes (/feed/entry) where link href != `http://myhomesite.com`.*

  As you can see, in the XPath expression we prepend the `x` prefix to the element node names, i.e. `x:entry` and `x:link` to ensure we address the elements in the correct namespace.
- **`/path/to/file.rss`** - A pathname to the source `.rss` file.

#### Saving the resultant XML (RSS)

To save the resultant XML you can either:

1. Add the `--inplace` option to the aforementioned command - this will overwrite the original `.rss` with the desired result. For instance:

   ```
    xml ed --inplace -N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -d '//x:entry[not(child::x:link[@href="https://myhomesite.com"])]' /path/to/file.rss
   ```
2. Or, utilize the [redirection operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (`>`) and specify a pathname to the the location at which to save the output. For instance the following compound command will save the results to a new file:

   ```
    xml ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -d '//x:entry[not(child::x:link[@href="https://myhomesite.com"])]' /path/to/file.rss > /path/to/results.rss
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** The `/path/to/results.rss` at the end of the aforementioned compound command should be substituted with a real pathname to where you want to save the new file.</sub>

#### XPath with `local-name()`:

Given that your example source XML (RSS) does not include any [QNames](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/qnameids.html) it's also possible to utilize XPath's [`local-name()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256070(v%3Dvs.100)) function. This will negate the need to bind the namespace using XMLStarlet's `-N` option. For example:

```
xml ed -d '//*[local-name() = "entry" and not(child::*[local-name() = "link"][@href="https://myhomesite.com"])]' /path/to/file.rss
```

---

**IMPORTANT:** You *may* need to substitute the leading `xml` part in all the example commands shown in this post with `xmlstarlet` instead. For example:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -d '//x:entry[not(child::x:link[@href="https://myhomesite.com"])]' /path/to/file.rss.
^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

**Edit:**

Given your example XML it's also possible to utilize a simplified syntax for the default namespace, which is to use `_:` instead `x:`. By using an underscore (`_`) you don't need to utilize the `-N` option to bind the namespace to a prefix. Refer to the section titled [1.3. A More Convenient Solution](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html#idm47989546151216) in the XMLStarlet documentation for further information regarding this feature.

For instance:

```
xml ed -d '//_:entry[not(child::_:link[@href="https://myhomesite.com"])]' /path/to/file.rss
```

To further understand using XMLStarlet when your source XML uses namespaces I suggest also reading [Namespaces and default namespace](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html) in the documentation.

---

**Edit 2:**

The author of the OP subsequently wrote the following in the comments:

> One question more. Condition `[not(child::_:link[@href="myhomesite.com"])]` is strict. I wanna be something like start with `myhomesite.com` but URI not important i.e. `myhomesite.com**anything**`. It's possible? [sic]
>
> something like this.. `xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -d '//x:entry[not(child::x:link[matches(@href, '^https://myhomesite.com/' )]/@href)]' feed.rs`

Consider utilizing Xpath's [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) Function with any one of the previously given examples. For example:

- Using the `-N` option and `starts-with()`:

  ```
  xml ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -d '//x:entry[not(child::x:link[starts-with(@href, "https://myhomesite.com")])]' file.rss
  ```
- Using the `local-name()` and `starts-with()`:

  ```
  xml ed -d '//*[local-name() = "entry" and not(child::*[local-name() = "link"][starts-with(@href, "https://myhomesite.com")])]' file.rss
  ```
- Using the simplified syntax for the default namespace, i.e. an underscore, and `starts-with()`:

  ```
  xml ed -d '//_:entry[not(child::_:link[starts-with(@href, "https://myhomesite.com")])]' file.rss
  ```