# xmlstarlet | Edit xml. What i do wrong?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have simple XML (rss feed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="self" href="http://ushakova.city/articles/feed/"/>
  <updated>2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</updated>
  <id>http://myurl/articles/feed/?dt=2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</id>
  <entry>
    <id>http://myurl/articles/117/</id>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://yandex.ru/news/story/V_Tyumenskom_rajone_vybirayut_luchshego_pomoshhnika_vospitatelya--5d543025944f00fecce8c11031573354?lang=ru&amp;amp;from=rss&amp;amp;stid=cF2eQWK2DdnB"/>
    <author>
      <name/>
    </author>
    <published>2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</published>
    <updated>2019-11-04T12:45:00Z</updated>
    <title type="html"><![CDATA[В Тюменском районе выбирают лучшего помощника воспитателя]]></title>
    <content type="html"><![CDATA[]]></content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

validate

```
xmlstarlet val _1.xml 
_1.xml - valid
```

see structure

```
xmlstarlet el _1.xml 

feed
feed/title
feed/link
feed/updated
feed/id
feed/entry
feed/entry/id
feed/entry/link
feed/entry/author
feed/entry/author/name
feed/entry/published
feed/entry/updated
feed/entry/title
feed/entry/content
```

try remove  section

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//entry" _1.xml
xmlstarlet ed -d "/feed/entry" _1.xml
```

and nothing.. I have few questions.

1. what i do wrong?
2. How remove  section?
3. How remove  section if link/@href do not started with http://myurl

Comment: You need to take the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace into account. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44186213/407651

Comment: @mzjn  xmlstarlet ed -N WHAT-PREFIX-HERE=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom ?

Comment: There is a simplified syntax for the default namespace (see answer to linked question). This should work for you: `xmlstarlet ed -d "//_:entry" _1.xml`.

Comment: @mzjn Tnanks! Worked! And last question. How delete entry node if link@href != http://myurl. May be use regexp? Its possible ?

Comment: Use similar approach to what's suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706146/bash-remove-xml-nodes-if-the-attribute-value-of-a-child-node-does-not-equal-a/58728029#58728029) to your last question, i.e. Use the `-N` option to bind the namespace to an arbitrarily named `x` prefix. Then reference the elements using `x:feed` and `x:entry`. For instance: `xml ed -N x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -d "/x:feed/x:entry" _1.xml` - See [Common problems: Namespaces and default namespace](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html) in docs. Or use a `local-name()` function.

Comment: @AntonShevtsov - Your point no. 3, i.e. _"How remove [sic] section if link/@href do not started with `http://myurl`"_ -  How does that differ from what you asked in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706146/bash-remove-xml-nodes-if-the-attribute-value-of-a-child-node-does-not-equal-a/58728029) ? What _"section"_ are you referring to this time?

Comment: @RobC thanks! I comment your answer in my previous question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash - Remove XML nodes if the attribute value of a child node does not equal a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706146/bash-remove-xml-nodes-if-the-attribute-value-of-a-child-node-does-not-equal-a)